# Batch convert of Word docs with images to HTML

Tags: microsoft-word, batch, html, file-conversion

**OK, here is my situation:**
I made a knowledge base for a company, they have about 500 word documents with screenshots in them explaining procedures and such. I can easily paste the text into the cms wysiwyg editor on the knowledge base but the images need to be uploaded one at a time, then sized and placed in the article.

**Question:**
Is there any suggestions for an automatic method to to convert the documents to html with the appropriate image tags and links to the images in them, and export/package the images for ftp upload? I can already convert them to HTML automatically using a batch file and a program, but converting the images to the correct tags with href link, then exporting them for ftp is where i need some help.

Might not even be possible, but if anyone has tried to do something like this I would like to here how you approached this.

Comment: Some CMS editors have the ability to accept pasted images and auto-add those as linked resources (atlassian's confluence editor for one)... Can you tell us which CMS you are using?

Comment: I am using KBpublisher, the editor is CKEditor. I was looking at Confluence, it looks very nice, but we already paid for KBpublisher and set it up. I think I am going to try porting them over using Powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using this [Powershell script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/bshukla/archive/2010/07/29/how-to-convert-a-word-document-to-other-formats-using-powershell.aspx) would be the best way, but you might need some editing.
Give it a shot, and tell me what you've got.